# Python - How to loop through rows of text, and replace characters?

Tags: python, pandas

I just can't seem to get this right.

I now have a Pandas series called `text`

It consists of 105 rows of article text.

I want to loop through each of these rows and replace certain characters like " and -. Here's my code

```
cleaned = []
for i in text:
    i.replace('“', '')
    i.replace('”', '')
    i.replace('–', '')
    cleaned.append(i)
```

However, when I try to print out the text in this cleaned list, the characters above aren't removed. Where am I going wrong? Thanks

```
for i in cleaned:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

string.replace() returns the string with the replaced values. It doesn't modify the original so do something like this:

```
for i in text:
    i = i.replace('“', '')
    i = i.replace('”', '')
    i = i.replace('–', '')
    cleaned.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions to clean your text. The syntax can be a little confusing when you start, but it's much more powerful when you need to up your text cleaning.

```
import re

cleaned = []
for i in text:
    i = re.sub(r'\“', '', i)
    i = re.sub(r'\”', '', i
    i = re.sub(r'_', '', i)
    cleaned.append(i)
```

You can also replace all non letters and numbers using

```
i = re.sub(r'\W', '', i)
```

Remember that \ is for character escapes.